# Log4net Filter logs by which can show or not to the customer

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to save and filter logs based on which I need to show to customer and which I should not in log4net. I tried to achieve that based on Severity levels where
I tried some thing like this

```
    Logger logger = new Logger(); // My logger class
    logger.Write(Level.Info, "Main Method", "log Message", loggingParameters);
    logger.Write(Level.Finest, "Main Method", "different log Message for customer", loggingParameters);
```

And now i will filter these to only show the logs with level Finest to customer. Is there any other way of achieving the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can doe this with defining different loggers:

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));//normal logger
ILog customerlogger= LogManager.GetLogger("customerlogger");//customer logger
```

Now you can log to the different logger like:

```
logger.Info("my log message");
customerlogger.Info("customer log message");
```

Now you can differencate between the logger in you configuration:

```
<root>
   ...
</root>
<logger name="customerlogger">
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="CustomerAppender" />
</logger>
```

Next you can remove the customerlogger messages with a filter from you 'normal' appenders.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that if the custom logger should not inherit appenders from the root logger then `additivity=false` would have to be added in the logger declaration.